# Multiple BSODs on acer notebook

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-8, bsod

I've recently bought an Acer Travelmate notebook. Initially it came with Windows 7 on it and I got BSODs whenever I tried to do heavy stuff (like games and etc) on it. Though very often I got a BSOD even when doing light things like browsing the internet. When playing games the BSOD is almost 100% guaranteed!

Then  I installed windows 8 but still got these BSODs:

`page fault in nonpaged area`

`memory management`

`system thread exception not handled`

Then I installed Ubuntu and it works almost fine, but I still occasionally get `kernel NULL pointer reference` error.

I guess there might be a problem with the ram? Or is it something else?

Comment: [Tracking down random BSOD on windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/130786/tracking-down-random-bsod-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely to be a RAM-related issue. Run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to make sure, then replace the faulty RAM module or RMA/return the device.